# Как найти индекс элемента в двумерном массиве

Tags: c#, datagridview

Реализовываю замену элемента в массиве по индексу через DGV.
Выглядит следующим образом (получаю значение элемента по выделенной ячейке DGV):

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
        textBox1.Text = s;
    }
```

Вопрос вот в чем, каким образом можно получить индекс элемента в выбранной ячейке? Пробовал следующим образом, но не вышло, получаю общий размер массива:

```
textBox2.Text = a.GetLength(0).ToString() + " // " + a.GetLength(1).ToString();
```

Comment: Каким образом этот код `textBox2.Text = a.GetLength(0).ToString() + " // " + a.GetLength(1).ToString();` поможет вам найти элемент?

Comment: @tym32167 никак, раз использовав его, сразу понял.

Answer (score 1):

Чтоб не заниматься бестолковой ерундой, т.е. не писать такое

```
textBox1.Text = "Фигня";
```

или

```
var selectedCell = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
```

Уже во второй версии Windows Forms были придуманы **Data Bindings** или по-русски **Привязка данных**.

Допустим мы в программе работаем с классом

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Создадим такой интерфейс

[image: дизайн интерфейса]

У DGV создадим необходимые столбцы с указанием к какому свойству необходимо привязаться
[image: свойства столбца]

Для привязывания коллекции людей к DGV и текстбоксам, будем использовать класс [BindingSource](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Вот код формы с комментариями

```
public partial class MainView : Form
{
    //данные для приложения
    private AppDataContext _data = new AppDataContext();

    //источник данных (Люди) для контролов 
    private BindingSource _bsPeople = new BindingSource();

    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //установка привязок
        SetBindings();

        //загрузка данных
        LoadData();

        //настройка окна
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "Пример работы с привязками";
    }

    private void SetBindings()
    {
        //определяем тип источника данных
        _bsPeople.DataSource = typeof(List<Person>);

        //привязка для DGV
        _dataGridViewPeople.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        _dataGridViewPeople.DataSource = _bsPeople;

        //привязка у текстбоксов
        _textBoxFirstName.DataBindings.Add("Text", _bsPeople, nameof(Person.FirstName));
        _textBoxLastName.DataBindings.Add("Text", _bsPeople, nameof(Person.LastName));
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        _bsPeople.DataSource = _data.GetPeople();
    }
}
```

И так это работает

[image: пример работы примера]

Заметьте мы установили только привязки. Мы в DGV не занимаемся поиском выбранного человека и извлечением данных из его свойств, все за нас делают привязки!

Пример можно скачать [здесь](https://yadi.sk/d/T3z4NVajOOuwlg)